# Confine the movement of a UIDragItem within a specified set of sections in UITableview drag & drop interaction

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, drag-and-drop, uidragitem

I have used UITableView's drag and drop interaction to reorder a UITableView. I need to prevent the user from dragging the cell outside of a particular section. If the user drags the finger outside that section, the dragged cell should not move along with the finger. It should rather stay at the edge of the section's frame until the user drags into the section again. Please help me out with your answer and thank you in advance!!!